# How did d3js.org create the hexagonal grid on their home page?

Tags: css, d3.js

On [d3js.org](http://d3js.org) they have this sea of hexagons that is fully interactive, but there are no d3 docs that show how one would even start to make something like this.

[image]

From inspecting the source, you can see it's made with something called hexbin and d3js itself, but there's no other source code that actually helps understand how it's made.

Can anyone shed light on how they implemented this?

Comment: Well as you say the implementation is available completely. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff where? All I saw were the libraries they used, but not the actual implementation.

Comment: Looks like lines 270-512.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff oh wow I didn't see that using inspect element, but it showed up in view page source. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Lars Kotthoff this is how they did it assuming you have a structure called `data`:

```
data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.i = i % 10;
  d.j = i / 10 | 0;
});

Math.seedrandom(+d3.time.hour(new Date));

d3.shuffle(data);

var height = 460,
    imageWidth = 132,
    imageHeight = 152,
    radius = 75,
    depth = 4;

var currentFocus = [innerWidth / 2, height / 2],
    desiredFocus,
    idle = true;

var style = document.body.style,
    transform = ("webkitTransform" in style ? "-webkit-"
        : "MozTransform" in style ? "-moz-"
        : "msTransform" in style ? "-ms-"
        : "OTransform" in style ? "-o-"
        : "") + "transform";

var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
    .radius(radius);

if (!("ontouchstart" in document)) d3.select("#examples")
    .on("mousemove", mousemoved);

var deep = d3.select("#examples-deep");

var canvas = deep.append("canvas")
    .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var svg = deep.append("svg")
    .attr("height", height);

var mesh = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "example-mesh");

var anchor = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "example-anchor")
    .selectAll("a");

var graphic = deep.selectAll("svg,canvas");

var image = new Image;
image.src = "ex.jpg?3f2d00ffdba6ced9c50f02ed42f12f6156368bd2";
image.onload = resized;

d3.select(window)
    .on("resize", resized)
    .each(resized);

function drawImage(d) {
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, -radius);

  for (var i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
    var angle = i * Math.PI / 3,
        x = Math.sin(angle) * radius,
        y = -Math.cos(angle) * radius;
    context.lineTo(x, y);
  }

  context.clip();
  context.drawImage(image,
      imageWidth * d.i, imageHeight * d.j,
      imageWidth, imageHeight,
      -imageWidth / 2, -imageHeight / 2,
      imageWidth, imageHeight);
  context.restore();
}

function resized() {
  var deepWidth = innerWidth * (depth + 1) / depth,
      deepHeight = height * (depth + 1) / depth,
      centers = hexbin.size([deepWidth, deepHeight]).centers();

  desiredFocus = [innerWidth / 2, height / 2];
  moved();

  graphic
      .style("left", Math.round((innerWidth - deepWidth) / 2) + "px")
      .style("top", Math.round((height - deepHeight) / 2) + "px")
      .attr("width", deepWidth)
      .attr("height", deepHeight);

  centers.forEach(function(center, i) {
    center.j = Math.round(center[1] / (radius * 1.5));
    center.i = Math.round((center[0] - (center.j & 1) * radius * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3)) / (radius * 2 * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3)));
    context.save();
    context.translate(Math.round(center[0]), Math.round(center[1]));
    drawImage(center.example = data[(center.i % 10) + ((center.j + (center.i / 10 & 1) * 5) % 10) * 10]);
    context.restore();
  });

  mesh.attr("d", hexbin.mesh);

  anchor = anchor.data(centers, function(d) { return d.i + "," + d.j; });

  anchor.exit().remove();

  anchor.enter().append("a")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.example.url; })
      .attr("xlink:title", function(d) { return d.example.title; })
    .append("path")
      .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon());

  anchor
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; });
}

function mousemoved() {
  var m = d3.mouse(this);

  desiredFocus = [
    Math.round((m[0] - innerWidth / 2) / depth) * depth + innerWidth / 2,
    Math.round((m[1] - height / 2) / depth) * depth + height / 2
  ];

  moved();
}

function moved() {
  if (idle) d3.timer(function() {
    if (idle = Math.abs(desiredFocus[0] - currentFocus[0]) < .5 && Math.abs(desiredFocus[1] - currentFocus[1]) < .5) currentFocus = desiredFocus;
    else currentFocus[0] += (desiredFocus[0] - currentFocus[0]) * .14, currentFocus[1] += (desiredFocus[1] - currentFocus[1]) * .14;
    deep.style(transform, "translate(" + (innerWidth / 2 - currentFocus[0]) / depth + "px," + (height / 2 - currentFocus[1]) / depth + "px)");
    return idle;
  });
}
```

Comment: And what is the `data`'s structure ?

Comment: @m0meni, there is a copy-paste-typo at the end of the `resized()` function. Fully functioning playground: https://jsbin.com/cihoqirimu/edit?html,js,output